# Why using *args in defining functions is storing just one value

Tags: python, function, args

I am having a problem using *args in a function I am defining. Here is an example of one code:

```
def feet_to_meter(*args):
    """
    :param *args: numeric values in feet
    :output: returns list of values in meter
    """
    
    value_list = [ ]
    conversion_factor = 0.3048
    
    for arg in args:
        try:
            value_list.append(arg * conversion_factor)
        except TypeError:
            print(str(arg) + "is not a number")
        return value_list
        
print ("Function call with 3 values: ")
print(feet_to_meter(3, 1, 10))
```

I understand that the code should convert the 3 values but somehow after executing the program I only get the result of the first value. I am using Pydroid 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You call `return` inside the `for` loop, so it `return`s on the first item and the others are never processed at all.

Comment: If you want `return` to be run only after the loop completes (and has processed all three items), you need to change its indentation level so the word `return` is only indented as much as `for` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return value_list` needs to have one less tab. Working version below.

```
def feet_to_meter(*args):
    """
    :param *args: numeric values in feet
    :output: returns list of values in meter
    """
    
    value_list = [ ]
    conversion_factor = 0.3048
    
    for arg in args:
        try:
            value_list.append(arg * conversion_factor)
        except TypeError:
            print(str(arg) + "is not a number")
    return value_list
```

This happens because the `return` statement is executed on every iteration of the `for`, but a return will immediately exit the function after only one append has occurred. Placing the `return` at the same indentation as the `for` allows the `for` to finish executing before finally returning `value_list`